# PHPExcel Reading streamed files from aws s3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, phpexcel

I'm trying to read some Excel files that are stored in AWS S3 bucket, but for some odd reason, i'm having issues with .XLSX files and seems like .XLS files are behaving themselves.

I tried most of the answers in stack overflow but i think it has something to do with the streaming function of s3.

```
$xls_obj = array(
        'Bucket' => $attributes->report_bucket->StringValue,
        'Key'    => $attributes->report_key->StringValue
      );
$s3 = S3Client::factory(awsCred());
$s3->registerStreamWrapper();
$file = 's3://'.$xls_obj['Bucket'].'/'.$xls_obj['Key'];
```

This returns the file path that i can access. the file.
i then load this into my PHPExcel file. and when i try to identify it it shows it as HTML where as .XLS files shows as excel5.

i did try using

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

and

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
return $reader->load($file);
```

and this obviously gives me

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Invalid char in CDATA 0x3 in Entity, line: 1
```

because the identified format was HTML
I cannot get it to work with PUBLIC URL from S3 Either. so i need help!

Answer (score 2):

So after lots of reading online, i noticed that, PHPExcel Doesn't really like URL addresses, and that might be the reason that Identify() was giving me HTML as response.

So, Right now i managed to solve this issue by copying the file to a tmp file, read it then delete it. might not be the best solution, but for now it works.

in case you're wondering, that's how i did it.

```
  $s3 = S3Client::factory(awsCred());
  $xls_obj = array(
        'Bucket' => $Bucket,
        'Key'    => $KEY,
        'SaveAs' => $path_folder."/".$fileName
  );

  $file = 's3://'.$xls_obj['Bucket'].'/'.$xls_obj['Key'];
  $s3->getObject($xls_obj);
```

> awsCred() is array of s3 credentials

and then i used this function to return PHPExcel File:

```
function fileToExcelObj($file){
  /**
   * [fileToExcelObj description]
   * @param  {s3 Object} $file
   * @return {PHPExcel Obj}
  **/

  $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
  return $reader->load($file);

}
```

Comment: I am getting the error - Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception: Unable to identify a reader for this file

Comment: Did you find a direct solution yet?